# Can't enter recovery mode after crash while installing nvidia drivers

Tags: nvidia, kernel, 22.04, cuda, recovery-mode

Hi guys how are you? I have ubuntu 22.04 and everything was working fine until I decided to upgrade my current version of cuda to version 12. As always happens when installing nvidia drivers something crashed during the installation and I could't boot normally.

As I always do when this happens, I booted from recovery mode, deleted and purged all the nvidia drivers and cuda versions from my system and proceeded to install cuda 12 with the runfile provided by nvidia. During this process I got a kernel panic screen(never happened before) and after restarting I couldn't boot nor in normal mode neither in recovery mode, the screen remains black and I can only restart with REISUB.

Fortunately when I enter in "Advanced boot options for ubuntu" in GRUB I can choose to boot in recovery mode from two different versions of the kernel:
**linux-image-5.19.0-45-generic** and **linux-image-5.19.0-46-generic**. As the crash happened when installing the driver in version 5.19.0-46 (in recovery mode), if I choose version 5.19.0-45 I can boot in recovery mode normally. The problem is that I can only use the system in recovery mode with this kernel version. I need somehow to fix the other kernel in order to install the drivers there and be able to boot normally again. Or find some way to set the default kernel as 5.19.0-45. I'm a little bit afraid of trying to install cuda in this kernel and loose any chance of fixing it without reinsalling.

Do you know any approach I can take from here? I'm a little bit lost with this.

Sorry for the long text, cheers!